# On Solaris Sparc 64bit, Can a 64bit process load a 32 bit shared library

Tags: c, 64-bit

On a 64bit Solaris Sparc system, can an Apache Server built in 64bit mode load a 32 bit plug-in?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible.  When a 64 bit process tries to load a 32 bit shared object, the
runtime linker gives the following error:

> ld.so.1: app: fatal: ./lib32.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Answer (score 0):

On no sensible system 64-bit binary cannot load 32-bit shared library. They might pass pointers around, you know.